# How to do element-wise conditional indexing comparison in Theano?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, theano

The operation consists of two arrays `X` and `idx` of equal length where the values of `idx` can vary between 0 to (k-1) with the value of k given.

This is the general Python code to illustrate this.

```python
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(6) # Just for a sample of elements
k = 3
idx = numpy.array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1]]).T # Can only contain values in [0..(k-1)]
np.array([X[np.where(idx==i)[0]] for i in range(k)])
```

Sample output:

```
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3]])
```

Note that there is actually a reason for me to represent `idx` as a matrix and not as a vector. It was initialised to `numpy.zeros((n,1))` as part of its computation, where `n` the size of `X`.

I tried implement this in Theano like so

```python
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

X = T.vector('X')
idx = T.vector('idx')
k = T.scalar()
c = theano.scan(lambda i: X[T.where(T.eq(idx,i))], sequences=T.arange(k)) 
f = function([X,idx,k],c)
```

But I received this error at line where `c` is defined:

```
TypeError: Wrong number of inputs for Switch.make_node (got 1((<int8>,)), expected 3)
```

Is there a simple way to implement this in Theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `nonzero()` and correct the dimensions of `idx`.

This code solved the problem

```python
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

X = T.vector('X')
idx = T.vector('idx')
k = T.scalar()
c, updates = theano.scan(lambda i: X[T.eq(idx,i).nonzero()], sequences=T.arange(k)) 
f = function([X,idx,k],c)
```

For the same example, through the use of Theano:

```python
import numpy as np

X = np.arange(6) 
k = 3
idx = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1]]).T

f(X, idx.T[0], k).astype(int)
```

This gives the output as

```
array([[0, 4],
       [1, 5],
       [2, 3]])
```

If idx is defined as `np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1])`, then `f(X, idx, k)` can be used instead.